# How to mount a query to join by searching by last date

Tags: oracle, join

I have the following tables:
TB_PRODUCTS

```
ID     COD_PROD     Name  
===============================================
1       100    Video monitor
2       101    Keyboard
3       102    Mouse
```

TB_COSTS

```
COD_PROD    DATE_ATT    COST
===============================================
100        2016-03-01    1.00
100        2016-02-29    2.00
101        2016-03-01    1.00
101        2016-02-29    2.00
102        2016-03-01    1.00
102        2016-02-29    2.00
```

This is the query that I have:

```
SELECT
TB_PRODUCTS.ID,
TB_PRODUCTS.COD_PROD,
TB_PRODUCTS.Name,
TB_COSTS.DATE_ATT,
TB_COSTS.COST
FROM
TB_PRODUCTS
INNER JOIN TB_COSTS ON TB_COSTS.COD_PROD = TB_PRODUCTS.COD_PROD
WHERE
TB_COSTS.COST > 0
```

But the query does not return me the cost of the last date, and what I need is to do a join with the cost of the last date.
How could I filter the Join only taking the cost of the most recent date ?

Comment: What does `TB_` stand for?

Comment: I've got money on "Table"

Comment: @Phil TB_  is the table name prefix

Comment: I corrected a portion of the join what was written wrong

Comment: could you please add the expected output in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to use CTE (but I haven't tested the syntax myself). For example:

```
WITH ANSWER AS
(SELECT TB_COSTS.COD_PROD
    , TB_COSTS.DATE_ATT
    , TB_COSTS.COST
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TB_COSTS.COD_PROD ORDER BY DATE_ATT DESC) AS ORDER_VALUE
FROM TB_COSTS)

SELECT TB_PRODUCTS.ID
, TB_PRODUCTS.COD_PROD
, TB_PRODUCTS.Name
, ANSWER.DATE_ATT
, ANSWER.COSTS
FROM TB_PRODUCTS
INNER JOIN ANSWER on TB_PRODUCTS.COD_PROD = ANSWER.COD_PROD
AND ANSWER.ORDER_VALUE = 1
WHERE TB_COSTS.COST > 0
```